# Find direction of vehicle on road

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mapbox, plotly

I am working on a GPS data that has the latitude/longitude data speed vehicle ids and so on.

Each day different time vehicle speeds are different for each side of the road.

[image]

I created this graph with plotly mapbox and color difference is related with speed of vehicle.

So my question is Can I use any cluster algorithm for find side of vehicle? I tried DBSCAN but I could not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you have about the different spots, is you know time and speed at each point you can estimate the range within the next point should fail in, and afterwards order them in function of distance. Otherwise it is going to be complicated without more information that position and speed with all those points.

ps there is a heavy computational method to try to estimate the route by using tangent to determine the angle between segments os consecutive points

Answer (score 0):

Many GPS hardware sets will compute direction and insert this information into the standard output data alongside latitude, longitude, speed, etc.  You might check if your source data contains information about direction or "heading" often specified in degrees where zero degrees is regarded as North, 90 degrees is East, etc.  You may need to parse the data and convert from binary or ascii hexadecimal values to integer values depending on the data structure specifications which vary for different hardware designs.  If such data exists in your source, this may be a simpler and more reliable approach to determining direction.